# grep -e command to Return matching data

Tags: node.js, linux, shell, grep

I am checking the output pattern using grep command. But i am not able to understand why below command not giving result. (As i know -e is used to match pattern)

> node App.js | grep -e "65"

but this is returning the result. That is-65.

> node App.js | grep "65"

please note output of > node App.js file is 65.

[image]

Help me to understand the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

#### Hello

-e means "Using a simple regular expression". A simple regex is "^[a-zA-Z0-9].*$". For the output of your script is therefore...

```
node App.js | grep -o -e "[6][5]"
```

...your friend. And an extended regex Pattern...

```
node App.js | grep -o -E "[56]{2,2}"
```

...hits 55, 66, 56 and 65.